# Crystal Report Page Break based on Group Footer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Currently I am trying to convert code from delphi to C#.net. But I am stuck with this issue as described in the picture.

[image]

In .net I can select based on "GroupFooterSection" but in delphi I can select based on "GF". So I get the different index as described in picture. GroupFooterSection is in ascending order and Group Footer #Number is in Descending order.

Is there a way to read "Group Footer #8" instead of GroupFooterSection8 to get Index in .net. I see that in .net we have Sections[].SectionFormat but in Delphi its SectionFormat[].Section.

```
 ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
 foreach (var param in pageBreakList)
            {                   

                cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[int.Parse( param.NewPageAfter)].SectionFormat.EnableNewPageAfter = param.BNewPageAfter;
                cryRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections[int.Parse( param.ResetPageNAfter)].SectionFormat.EnableResetPageNumberAfter = param.BResetPageNAfter;

            }
```

When I manually put index and I see that the report is same for both languages. The only problem I faced is how to get the index based on "Group Footer #8" not GroupFooterSection8 in .net

Thank you.

Comment: use `groupinglevel` function in crystal.. that may help...